# Unable to change height of search bar and textfield inside it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
func configureSearchController()
    {

        resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
        resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self

        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
        //self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = []


        for subView in searchController.searchBar.subviews {
            for subViewOne in subView.subviews {
                if subViewOne is UITextField {
                    searchTextField = subViewOne as! UITextField
                    subViewOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

                    var currentTextFieldBounds = subViewOne.bounds
                    currentTextFieldBounds.size.height = 45
                    subViewOne.bounds = currentTextFieldBounds
                    break
                }
            }
        }


        extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
        definesPresentationContext = true

    }
```

This doesn't change height of text field unexpectedly. I also want to change height of search bar. What changes should I make here for the same to work?

Answer (score 1):

IMO, The search bar size shouldn't be changed as it's the native standard provided by Apple. Also the way you use of recursively searching of textfield is not recommended and not guaranteed to work in all iOS versions.

Maybe you can try to use custom Search bar with your own text field and u can easily play with it.