# Is it a good practice to modify the search bar height and its textfield height programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the following code. It doesn't seem to work either too.

```
func configureSearchController(){

resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self

self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
//self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = []


for subView in searchController.searchBar.subviews {
    for subViewOne in subView.subviews {
        if subViewOne is UITextField {
            searchTextField = subViewOne as! UITextField
            subViewOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            var currentTextFieldBounds = subViewOne.bounds
            currentTextFieldBounds.size.height = 45
            subViewOne.bounds = currentTextFieldBounds
            break
        }
    }
}

extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

If it is advisable to change them, how should I correct this code?

After Darshana's help, it is looking  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Gld.png), However I want something  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXIrM.png). When the search bar is active, it should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU8CN.png)

```
edited code:


var searchController : UISearchController!



     configureSearchController()



     func configureSearchController()
        {

            resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
            resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self

            self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
            //self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
            self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

            self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
            self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = []



           // searchController.searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70).isActive = true


            var image = self.getImageWithColor(color: UIColor.white, size:    CGSize(width: 20, height: 35))

            searchController.searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)

            image = self.getImageWithColor(color: UIColor.gray(), size:    CGSize(width: 20, height: 35))
            searchController.searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(image, for: .focused)

           // self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
            extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
            definesPresentationContext = true

        }
```

adding the code doesn't change search bar image when it is in focused state (active).

Comment: This is essentially a repost of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52207324/unable-to-change-height-of-search-bar-and-textfield-inside-it) with the extra thought added.

Comment: Sure it is @rmaddy. I thought to post a better form of the question.

Comment: Maybe delete your old question if this replaces it

Comment: @AshleyMills, alright!

Answer (score 0):

Its not advisable to change the height of the UITextField of a UISearchBar by iterating through the subviews of UISearchBar.

Why because is in future the Apple might decide to create UISearchBar with UILayer or any other component that they come up with, who knows.

If needed we can write our own custom component which can do the trick.

Having said that, if you still need the height to be changed you need to change its constraint like below but not directly assigning a value to its subview's height.

```
searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
```

Comment: this does not have any effect

Answer (score 0):

No, Its not advisable to change hight of UITextfield of UIsearchbar by iterating through subviews.

If you really need to change hight of textfield, you can do that by setting background image with using setSearchFieldBackgroundImage.

Height of textfield will be same as hight of provided image.

Example code : Swift 4.0

```
 func getImageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect = 
        CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 8.0)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    path.fill()
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
} 


let image = self.getImageWithColor(color: UIColor.lightGray, size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 45))
    searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal;
    searchBar.showsCancelButton  = true;
```

[image: Searchbar appearance after above code]

Comment: It doesn't work. It says: Value of type '(UIContentContainer, CGSize) -> CGSize' has no member 'width' ; Cannot convert value of type '(UIContentContainer, CGSize) -> CGSize' to expected argument type 'CGSize'

Comment: have copied code, which is working for me with swift 4.0. What swift version you are using?

Comment: Thank you @Darshana, it works like charm. Only thing is that rounded corners aren't working. And I want another image when it is in active mode. Please check edited question. Thank you for helping

Comment: Corner radius too, working for me.  Not sure why not working for you. what parameter you are passing in corner radius?  try changing "cornerRadius: 5.0"  to whatever radius you want. Try 0 first, so you will notice, its changing on 5.0

Comment: If you want cancel button, thats totally different question. btw, you can check Show cancel button from storyboard for search bar.

Comment: and for the colour too, You can set property of searcher style to minimal instead of prominent from storyboard. and use lightgray colour instead of white.

Comment: I had to remove the loop above and it worked fine. But what should be the case for it to work when it is in active mode? I want the grey colour. It isn't working.

Comment: you need to change background image of that colour when its active if you want different colour.

Comment: searchBar.delegate = self
        func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        
  
        let image1 = self.getImageWithColor(color: UIColor.lightGray, size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 45))
        searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(image1, for: .normal)
        
    }
    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        
        let image1 = self.getImageWithColor(color: UIColor.white, size: CGSize(width: 20, height: 45))
        searchBar.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(image1, for: .normal)
        
        
    }

Comment: Before you code more, I would advice to read UISearchbar document from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar